# Проблема при подключении библиотеки с зависимостями

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

У меня есть `APP` и `LIB1`, которая имеет зависимость от `LIB2`. Если `LIB1` я подключаю к `APP` как модуль, то все OK. Если `LIB1` к `APP` подключаю через `implementation files`, то при вызове метода из `LIB1` ругается `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.XXX.XXX.XLog" on path: DexPathList`. XLog - это класс в `LIB2`. Почему это происходит?

Comment: Вы бы показали как они у Вас прописаны, а то не очень-то понятно - может Вы в вопросе попутали `LIB1`, `LIB2`?. И что Вы вообще хотите - почему Вас не устраивает зависимость типа "модуль"? И да, зависимость `implementation` видна только этому модулю, но не его потребителю. Чтобы `APP` видел `LIB2` "сквозь" `LIB1` нужно в `LIB1` прописать `LIB2` как `api ...` (вместо `implementation ...`)

Comment: Я все верно описал. Из APP мне не нужен доступ к LIB2. Проблема решилась когда я подключил LIB2 к APP.